# Semiconductor Devices

Tags: semiconductor-physics

What happens when electrons and holes combine? I am studying forward biasing and it is troubling me a lot as to when and how the depletion layer is formed and when electrons and holes combine is a new covalent bond formed?

Answer (score 1):

When an electron (an electron in a semiconductor, that is to say, an electron
in the high energy "conduction band") combines with a hole (which is an
unoccupied and therefore available-for-tenancy state in the lower energy
"valence band"), what happens is a transition from high energy to lower
energy of an electron.   Sometimes, that means light emission.

The recombination of electrons with holes happens, as in an LED, because it
is returning a nonequilibrium imbalance (an excess of electrons) to thermal
equilibrium in a piece of P-type semiconductor.  Either that, or it returns
an excess of holes to thermal equilibrium in a piece of N-type semiconductor.

There's no bonding (or unbonding) occurring, though; it's just a normal
shuffling of electrons between energy levels in a semiconductor.   There's a
background of generation and recombination due to thermal fluctuations.